# How to make omxplayer not always on top?

Tags: python, omxplayer, tkinter

I am using [Adafruit's Video Looper](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/overview) to loop on a video using python script and omxplayer. Although, I made a few modifications. I want a popup window to appear when a GPIO button is pressed.

I have the GPIO and the python script for a tkinter window all done and working, but the omxplayer is always on top so my window don't appear.

I tested without the omxplayer active and I guarantee the popup window is working (and has 'always on top' on).

Is there any options on omxplayer to adjust that? Or should I take a totally different approach?

(I am also posting this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460882/how-to-make-omxplayer-not-always-on-top). I don't know which forum is better suited for the question)